# Why does my subprocess.call work only when shell = True? Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using subprocess.call() to execute commands from a specific directory.

Without using `shell = True`

```
scrcpyPath = "C:\\Users\\H\\Downloads\\scrcpy-win64-v1.14"
subprocess.call(["scrcpy", "--window-title", "'Mydevice'"], cwd = scrcpyPath)
```

I get the following error

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified.

I have managed to make it work using `shell = True'

```
subprocess.call(f"scrcpy --window-title 'Mydevice'", cwd = scrcpyPath, shell = True)
```

but it stops working when I add whitespace in the window title `Mydevice`.

```
subprocess.call(f"scrcpy --window-title 'My device'", cwd = scrcpyPath, shell = True)
```

I get the following error

ERROR: Unexpected additional argument: 1'

The reason I am using a formatted string is that I want the window title to be a variable, but again - it does not work when I add whitespace.

```
subprocess.call(f"scrcpy --window-title 'Device {deviceName}'", cwd = scrcpyPath, shell = True)
```

I found the solution. I think I was wrongly using `cwd`.

```
subprocess.call([f"{scrcpyPath}\\scrcpy", "--window-title", f"'{deviceName}'"])
```

Comment: With `shell = True`, python uses the shell to find where the binary file for the command `scrcpy` is located. If you don't use that, you need to tell python about the location of that binary yourself.

Comment: @rdas I am not sure what that means, but I will look it up. I thought the location is given by cwd.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't split your arguments properly; basically any space-separation in the command-line should be separate arguments, and no shell quoting is needed when they're passed as separate arguments. What you wanted was:

```
subprocess.call(["scrcpy", "--window-title", "Mydevice"], cwd=scrcpyPath)
```

Comment: I have tried that and I have tried `subprocess.call(["scrcpy"], cwd = scrcpyPath)`. It still does not work without `shell = True`. I get this error: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified